# Select ID based on row Number

Tags: sql

This is my table

```
|  | Id                                 |
|1 |07A83EA7-6E00-4265-906C-FF187FE18EB3|
|2 |B6C10F47-7DEE-4D2B-AA3D-FF27B8FC105C|
|3 |10F56030-0803-4133-B57B-FF3F941A0D60|
```

Is it possible to select the `Id` based off of the row number?

I've tried:

```
SELECT [Id],ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowLol, Id
```

But that isn't really functional for what i have intended as it generates a temporary field.

Desired functionality:

being able to iterate through all entries, and use that as a parameter for my `UPDATE` in the loop

```
--DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT Data FROM ProcessEventMessages WHERE Id='AEF11F7B-06C1-4C40-9806-0004CAC6A042')
-- This will only work for ONE instance. Hence why i need an iterative ID, to pass along here^

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (  
    message varchar(200) '$.message',
    machineId varchar(200) '$.machineId',
    machineName int '$.machineName',
    ipAddress varchar(200) '$.ipAddress',
    LocalTime datetime2(7) '$.time'
 )  AS ChangeTime;



--loop on id
DECLARE @loopCounter INT = 0;

WHILE @loopCounter < (SELECT count(Id) FROM ProcessEventMessages)
BEGIN
PRINT 'changing values...';

UPDATE ProcessEventMessages SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.time', FORMAT(DATEADD(hour,-2,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.time')),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')) WHERE ROWNUMBER = @loopCounter)
SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1;
END;

PRINT 'done';
GO
```

Suggestion:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @loopCounter INT = 0;
WHILE @loopCounter < (SELECT count(Id) FROM ProcessEventMessages)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changing...';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (  
    message varchar(200) '$.message',
    machineId varchar(200) '$.machineId',
    machineName int '$.machineName',
    ipAddress varchar(200) '$.ipAddress',
    LocalTime datetime2(7) '$.time'
 )  AS ChangeTime;

   ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowNo
    FROM ProcessEventMessages 
    )
    UPDATE CTE 

    SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.time', FORMAT(DATEADD(hour,-2,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.time')),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')) 
    WHERE RowNo = @loopCounter

   SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done';
GO
```

Attempt that crashed:

```
DECLARE @loopCounter INT = 0;

WHILE @loopCounter < (SELECT count(Id) FROM ProcessEventMessages)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changing...';
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT Data FROM ProcessEventMessages WHERE RowNo = @loopCounter) -- RowNo isn't declared here. Where would i move it?
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (  
        message varchar(200) '$.message',
        machineId varchar(200) '$.machineId',
        machineName int '$.machineName',
        ipAddress varchar(200) '$.ipAddress',
        LocalTime datetime2(7) '$.time'
     )  AS ChangeTime;

   ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowNo
    FROM ProcessEventMessages 
    )
    UPDATE CTE 

    SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.time', FORMAT(DATEADD(hour,-2,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.time')),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')) 
    WHERE RowNo = @loopCounter
    SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done';
GO
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @RowNrr int = (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowNrr FROM ProcessEventMessages)
SET @json = (SELECT Data FROM ProcessEventMessages WHERE @RowNrr = @loopCounter)
...
and then
...

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT @RowNrr
)

but it doesn't work :/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generates a new local field"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You must add your data and the expected output. If that's your data, it already has an Id as far as I see, so I don't get why are you adding a new one. In addition, you don't talk about the rdbms you are using

Comment: @IMSoP it isn't a permanent field in my table is what i meant, thats why it doesn't work for me in this situation.

Comment: @JaimeDrq I've provided a pseudo-version of what i have in mind. Hope that clarifies it more.

Comment: Incidentally, your example doesn't show the rows in order of `Id`, as far as I can tell, and ordering by what appears to be a GUID/UUID won't give you consistent row numbers when new entries are inserted. I'm kind of confused what you'd actually use this for.

Comment: Maybe what you actually need is a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/cursors?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah i looked at it, but didnt really understand How to use it. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using sql server as dbms, now if I understood your requirement correctly then you may looking for <kbd>[CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)</kbd>,

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [Id],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowNo
   FROM TableName
)
SELECT ID
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNo IN(1,2,3)
```

**UPDATED**

If you try to integrate your update command with cte form, then this may be looks like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Id ASC) AS RowNo
    FROM ProcessEventMessages 
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.time', FORMAT(DATEADD(hour,-2,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.time')),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff')) 
WHERE RowNo = @loopCounter
```

Note : I am not sure that row number on id will be consistent. since if new ID get inserted then there may be chance of change in row numbers.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's sort of what i had in mind. I'll update my entire query to the question to give more context.

Comment: Please see the line where `ROWNUMBER == @loopCounter`. Hopefully that clarifies the purpose of extracting the rownumber a bit more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Would you mind taking a look at the Suggestion part of the question, i tried to implement your solution, however, i am not sure i quite understand how to use your solution.

Comment: You integrated it correctly. Are you getting any error or no result in update operation.

Comment: Update: MSSMS crashed while performing the query haha. However, I think my part of the query is to blame. I cannot access the @json value for RowNo. Let me update the code to show you

Comment: I have to be able to re-use the `RowNo` elsewhere. Please see the example i created above :)

Answer (score -1):

```
select foo.*
from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rownum, * from mytable ) as foo
where rownum=5
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.